# Flink reference data advice/best practice

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Looking for some advice on where to store/access Flink reference data. Use case here is really simple - I have a single column text file with a  list of countries. I am streaming twitter data and then matching the countries from the text file based on the (parsed) Location field of the tweet. In the IDE (Eclipse) its all good as I have a static ArrayList populated when the routine fires up via a static Build method in my Flink Mapper (ie implements Flinks MapFunction). This class is now inner static as it gets shirt on serialization otherwise. Point is, when the overridden map function is invoked at runtime from within the stream, the static array of country data is their waiting, fully populated and ready to be matched against. Works a charm. BUT, when deployed into a Flink cluster ( and it took me to hell and back last week to actually get the code to FIND the text file), the array is *only* populated as part of the Build method. When it comes to being used the data has mysteriously disappeared and I am left with an array size of 0. (ergo, not a lot of matches get found. Thus, 2 questions - why does it work in Eclipse and not on deploy (renders a lot of Eclipse unit tests pointless as well). Or possibly just more generally, what is the right way to cross reference this kind of static, fixed reference data within Flink? (and in a way that it is found in both Eclipse and the cluster...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to handle static reference data is to load the data in the `open` method of a [`RichMapFunction` or `RichFlatMapFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/api_concepts.html#rich-functions). Rich functions have `open` and `close` methods that are useful for creating and finalizing local state, and can access the runtime context.

Comment: Perfect. Moved the 'Build' method that was populating the reference data into the 'Open' method of the RichMapFunction and it all worked. (On reflection mind, I think its probably better to move this into some sort of pre-Flink processing so the ref data is already part of the data Flink is consuming from Kafka in the first place - but its still very nice that this  works.